# Android: Vibrations

Tags: android

I have a slight problem implementing vibration functionality in my application. 
My code is:

```
public class VibrationActivity extends Activity {

private Vibrator vib;

private long[] pattern = { 0, 500, 200, 500 };

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

vib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
int id = v.getId();

if (id == R.id.button1) {
vib.vibrate(pattern, -1);
}
}

}
```

I have declared the using statement in the manifest also so that's not the issue. When ever I click on a button nothing actually happens... Any one got any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't forget to register the onClickListener for your button.

Comment: It's with in the onClick event, there are a series of buttons, but i just indcluded one in the code snippit above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code :

```
public class testVibrate extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private Vibrator vib;
    private long[] pattern = { 0, 500, 200, 500 };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        vib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vib.vibrate(pattern, -1);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate() use:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
vib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view) {
        vib.vibrate(pattern, -1);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to inflate the layout in order to find the button by its id.
and then attach a listener to the button.

```
 public class VibrationActivity extends Activity {  
    private Vibrator vib;

    private Button button;

    private long[] pattern = { 0, 500, 200, 500 };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        vib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            int id = v.getId();

            if (id == R.id.button1)
            {
                vib.vibrate(pattern, -1);
            }
        }
    };

}
```